# Parsing Json failure

Tags: c#, json, encryption, aes

I have problem with reading from encrypted files.  have 2 sources of files, one is Rapsberry PI (Java), the second is desktop appliaction (.Net 4.6.1).

When I'm creating a encrypted file on my device and then want to read it in my desktop app, there is no problem with decrypting and encoding to string.

In the same app I create the same file, adding next element to list in the file on each 5s. When I read the file in my app, I got `Unexpected end when reading json. path` error.

I have checked models and they are both the same and valid.

For encryption/decryption I'm using AES algorithm.

There is my code from my desktop app:

Writing data:

```
Aes myAes = Aes.Create();
myAes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcde");
byte[] roundtrip = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(output, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);


DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
string pathSave =info + "\\test.plkx";
using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream (pathSave , FileMode.Append))
{
    sourceStream.Write(roundtrip, 0, roundtrip.Length);
};
```

The method `byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)`

```
using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    aesAlg.Key = Key;
    aesAlg.IV = IV;
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

     // Create the streams used for encryption.
     using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
     {
         using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
         {
             using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
             {

                 //Write all data to the stream.
                 swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
              }
                  encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
          }
      }
}

// Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
return encrypted;
```

There is my reader:

```
byte[] data = null;
data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
fileStream.Position = 0;
fileStream.Read(data, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
Aes myAes = Aes.Create();
myAes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcde");
byte[] roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(data, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
return new MemoryStream(roundtrip);
```

And `byte[] DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)` method:

```
byte[] plaintext = null;
using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aesAlg.Key = Key;
    aesAlg.IV = IV;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
        }
            plaintext = msDecrypt.ToArray();
            var ads = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(plaintext);


            //There I got exception 
            var ab = DeserializeStream(new MemoryStream(plaintext));


        }
    }
return plaintext;
```

`DeserializeStream` method:

```
public RecorderValueTest DeserializeStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    RecorderValueTest r = new RecorderValueTest();
    using (BsonDataReader reader = new BsonDataReader(stream))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
         r = serializer.Deserialize<RecorderValueTest>(reader);
    }
    return r;
}
```

## edit

I have tried this:

```
xxx = new xxx
{
    data = listRecord,
};
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(plkx);
```

```
try
{
    using (BsonDataReader reader = new BsonDataReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output))))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var r = serializer.Deserialize<xxx>(reader);
    }
} catch (Exception exc)
{ }
```

and still get the same error while deserialization. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<xxx>(plkx);` also didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to read to string first to see how it looks like?

Comment: Yeah,the string which I write on desktop app is the same which I read from selected file. But I see that when I read file from Rapsberry, there are some strange digits: `P?\u0003\0\u0012fileTime\0w??1a\u0001\0\0\u0002fileType\0\u0005\0\0\0DATA....` And for thar file reading and deserializing works.